# Git push works in Git Bash but not in SmartGit or TortoiseGit

Tags: git, git-bash, tortoisegit, smartgit

So I've created a repo using Git Bash, and it works (Local and Remote repo on github.com).
I've pushed README file for testing, and it worked. In my config everything seems okay:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[gui]
    pruneduringfetch = true
    encoding =
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:SOME_USERNAME/some-project-name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

And `$ ssh -V git@github.com` gives:

> Hi SOME_USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does
>   not provide shell access.

And I'm able to push files and everything, but only through Git Bash.
However, I've tried to work with  and it gave me the following error:

> The remote end hung up unexpectedly

When I manually changed the "origin" url to this:

> https://SOME_USERNAME@github.com/SOME_USERNAME/some-project.git

It worked. So it doesn't work with "git@..." but do work with "https://..".
I've tried another program - SmartGit. It also gives me

> The remote end hung up unexpectedly

but when I try to do this "change url trick" in SmartGit, for "https://..." it gives me the following error:

> Push: Authentication failed
>
> Authentication failed Setting remote
>
> Setting remote service path not supported by protocol.

I'm completely lost with all this stuff. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know if TortoiseGit and GitBash are using the same ssh keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running SmartGit as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it doesn't work with the "git@" url but works with the "https" shows that this is to do with your SSH key setup. Make sure you had chosen the "OpenSSH" option ( and not PUTTY) for TortoiseGit and in the settings page for TortoiseGit verify that the "Remote" section points to the place where your keys are placed.

Comment: Yes, I've chosen OpenSSH in the setup.

Answer (score 1):

SSH will look for keys in `%HOME%/.ssh`, which ("`HOME`") isn't always defined (msysgit will define it by default, maybe TortoiseGit but [you can specify your ssh keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key/198614#198614), probably not [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html))

So make sure HOME is set to **`%userprofile%`**, before launching SmartGit.