# git push works, but not git push origin master

Tags: git, git-bash, git-push

I am using Git Bash on Windows 10. I have cloned a repository to my PC, added files to it and made commits.

When I try the command:

`git push origin master`

I get this error:

`fatal: couldn't find remote ref master`

But if I try a simple `git push`, there is no error and the changes are reflected in my remote repo.
The same is true with the `pull` command. What's going wrong and how do I fix this?

**Edit: Based on the comments and the answers, I am adding this info.**

When I do a `git branch -avv` I get the following output:

```
* main                f42878d [origin/main] Added some more Week 1 problems
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main f42878d Added some more Week 1 problems
```

So, I tried what one of the answers suggested, which is to try `git push origin main` instead of `git push origin master`. This is my output:

```
warning: setting remote service path not supported by protocol
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
warning: setting remote service path not supported by protocol
Everything up-to-date
```

It does seem to work, but there are warnings before that. I googled the warning and found [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692627/git-push-works-in-git-bash-but-not-in-smartgit-or-tortoisegit). Based on the accepted answer, I ran GitBash as administrator, but the warning persists. What happens is that the authentication happens twice: once normally through a GitHub Login dialog box where I put my username and password. This fails, then an OpenSSH dialog box where I provide my username and password. This works.

I am new to Git Bash, so I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: What's the tracking branch on the remote for your current branch? Are you on master locally, even?

Comment: Can we see the result of `git branch -avv` ?

Comment: I have edited the question with the updated information.

Comment: You indeed don't have a remote master, so that error shouldn't be surprising. It's not really clear why, if you can just `git push` (i.e. the correct tracking branch is set), it's a problem that you can't `git push <remote> <branch>`).

Comment: This looks like a Windows ssh issue, rather than anything to do with Git itself. (Git for Windows tends to come with a version of ssh—just like it comes with a version of bash, which Windows people call "git bash" but it's really just bash-for-Windows—because the standard Windows tools were, for so many decades, so poor. Modern Windows has better tools now, apparently, but I don't actually use Windows so I don't have the whole answer for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `git push origin main`
This is because in GitHub master is addressed as main.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the remote will have a main branch, either, or that if it exists it matches what you're on locally. *"master is addressed as main"* is simply not true; the default branch for newly-created repos is now named main, there isn't a branch named master by default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this answer did seem to work though, although I received warnings before that. I have made edits to the question accordingly.

Comment: @justauser it will work _if_ there's a main branch on the remote and _if_ it is the correct branch for the local branch you're trying to push to it. But it's not a general solution and contains false information. Also that's the point of setting a tracking branch, so you don't have to specify every time.